# Why does my custom Magento Module override the entire core module and produce no results?

Tags: magento

I have been working on my first Magento module which is designed to extend the class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head and change the functionality of getDefaultTitle(). Simple right?

I create a new file called Title.php in my module directory local/Company/Metadata/Block directory and in Title.php is the following code:

```
<?php
class Company_Metadata_Block_Title extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
{

}
```

I have not even started to adjust the functionality of getDefaultTitle() and I already seem to be missing the boat.

When I upload the new module, it overrides the entire Head content of the page created by the Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head and I end up with empty head tags in my Html. Like this:

```
<head></head>
```

Where am I going wrong?  Shouldn't the above code (or lack of) in Title.php let the extended class do it's thing until told to do so otherwise?

Here is my config file for the module:

```
<config>

<modules>
    <Company_Metadata>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Company_Metadata>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <page>
            <rewrite>
                <html_head>Company_Metadata_Block_Title</html_head>
            </rewrite>
        </page>
    </blocks>
</global>

</config>
```

Comment: When you say config file, is this your entire etc/config.xml, do you have a xml for app/etc/modules/Company_Metadata.xml as well?

Comment: Yes, the above is my entire config.xml stored in the local/Company/Metadata/etc/config.xml . The /app/etc/modules/Company_Metadata.xml is built and loaded as well.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253284/magento-block-override-stops-phtml-from-displaying – I made the rookie mistake of not nesting my folders properly based on class name when I ended up with empty <head></head>

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you must declare your block class in the config.xml. Indeed, Magento understands that you want to override Head but doesn't find the Block classes to use.

Please try with this config.xml :

```
<modules>
    <Company_Metadata>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Company_Metadata>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>


        <metadata>
            <class>Company_Metadata_Block</class>
        </metadata>


        <page>
            <rewrite>
                <html_head>Company_Metadata_Block_Title</html_head>
            </rewrite>
        </page>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Comment: Thanks vrnet.  I will give this a try and let you know my results.  It makes sense.  Question: should the <metadata> tags nested in the <blocks> section above actually be <company_metadata> ?

Comment: If your module uses Blocks (let's say "view-models" for Magento), you must define how Magento access them in the config.xml. So not adding this node is really a mistake as soon as you add php files in the /Block folder of your module. This is the same for models and helpers. As for the use of <metadata> this a standard : you must use the module name, lower case (metadata) whereas "Company" is your namespace you can use for other modules. For Magento core, the namespace is "Mage" and modules are ie : Newsletter, Catalog, Customer... So Mage_Newsletter, Mage_Catalog, Mage_Customer and so on.

Comment: You are not forced to use a lowercase "metadata", that is only the convention. Whatever you choose there is what you will have to use in layouts when specifying the type; `<block type="metadata/title">`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have output disabled for you module. Rewrites still handled with disabled output but module can't show anything even if it calls parent methods

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and declare getTitle() and return the parent method. Also the `<modules>` node should be in app/etc/modules/Company_Metadata.xml while yours will work since Magento combines all of the xml into one big tree it is for consistencies (sanity) sake.  Also there are many other methods in Head.php, see if those are still working properly, if so then your xml rewrites are working properly.

```
<?php
class Company_Metadata_Block_Title extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
{
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return parent::getTitle();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your recommendation and it still give me the same result, empty head tags.  Which would mean that none of the methods in Head.php are able to run.  Would that mean that something is wrong with my rewrite?

Comment: Tried clearing Magento's cache?  Also you can validate that Magento is loading your module if you have the Company_Metadata.xml file setup properly in the admin->system->configuration->advanced

Comment: Cache is cleared.  From I can see the module is loading.  1) It displays in the configuration->advanced 2)when I load the module it wrecks the frontend because it's removing or rewriting all of the head content of the page.  Therefore no CSS or metadata renders.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but since I ran into a similar issue today and fixed it I thought I would share my solution for future reference.

I had the same issue and turned out the problem was caused by the fact that the compilation feature was turned on. So Magento picks up the configuration changes but can't load the new code as it's not part of the compiled code. Disabling compilation or running the compilation process again fixed the problem for me.